# Python simple code i cant fix help1!1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def print_guessed(secret_word):
    new_word = secret_word
    for i in new_word:
        i = "-"
    return new_word
print print_guessed("claptrap")
```

this jjust prints claptrap instead of --------
how to fix?

Comment: `return re.sub("[a-zA-Z]","-",secret_word)`

Comment: First, string is immutable, so `I='-'` won't change the value of `I` in `new_word`. So you end up just assigning `-` to a variable `I` and doing nothing. What you can do is `new_word  = list(secret_word)` and iterate through the positions... `for I in range(len(new_word)): new_word[I] = '-'`.. and then just retuning the joined string `''.join(new_word)`

Comment: Strings are immutable, loop variables don't work like that at all, and you really need a basic tutorial.

Comment: How is this `python-requests`? i removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
def print_guessed(secret_word):
    return '-'*len(secret_word)
```

The problem with your code is that you are trying to modify a string by its index. However `str` object in Python is not mutable. You have to construct a new string.

Note that this function returns the same result as other people have proposed. However it is much simpler (and may be faster) as it does not require looping.

Comment: I think doing `i='-'` is just a test, op probably wants to change a char in a string for any other given char..

Comment: @RafaelC Which is exactly what my code is doing: "replacing" all chars by `'-'` –– to construct a new string of `'-'` with the same length

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_guessed(secret_word):
    return ''.join('-' for i in secret_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an answer with a `for loop` instead of more efficient+compact list comprehension, this would do. Most elegant answer is often not easy to understand for beginners (from my experience) so hopefully this helps.

```
def print_guessed(secret_word):
    new_word = ''
    for i in secret_word:
        new_word += '-'
    return new_word
print(print_guessed("claptrap"))
```

In the above, we are adding '-' to `new_word`(initially empty) for each character in `secret_word` variable.

As many people pointed out, strings are immutable in Python. Notice that `new_word` is assigned a new value (instead of being modified by indexing) at each iteration inside the `for loop`.